# Why can't I use a class that implements List<X> where a List<X> is expected?

Tags: java, generics

First the simple case (A):

```
public class PsList implements List<Ps> { ... }
```

elsewhere

```
private void doSomething(List<Ps> list) { ... }

// compiles
List<Ps> arrayList = new ArrayList<Ps>();
doSomething(arrayList);

// does not compile
PsList psList = new PsList();
doSomething(psList);
```

Ok. I know that I can change this to "work" by adding ? extends as such:

```
private void doSomething(? extends List<Ps> list) { ... }

// compiles
List<Ps> arrayList = new ArrayList<Ps>();
doSomething(arrayList);

// compiles
PsList psList = new PsList();
doSomething(psList);
```

My question is why do I ***need*** to do that? It makes no sense to me. I am implementing the exact interface that is is expecting. I can pass other List types other than ArrayList why not mine?

Life is always more complicated than this, so my real coding issue is (B):

```
public class PsList implements List<Ps> { ... }

private void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends List<Ps>> map, Boolean custom) {
...

// need to create a new List<Ps> of either an ArrayList<Ps> or PsList
map.put("stringValue", custom ? new PsList() : new ArrayList<Ps>());

...
}
```

So, in either case Java is complaining that map is expecting ? extends List as the value.

even if I change this to be:

```
List<Ps> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Ps> psList = new PsList();
map.put("string", custom ? psList : list);
```

and of course this doesn't compile:

```
? extends List<Ps> list = new ArrayList<>();
? extends List<Ps> psList = new PsList();
map.put("string", custom ? psList : list);
```

So what am I supposed to do to get something like this to work?

Edit 1:
Ok, a minimal reproduction:

Ps.java

```
package com.foo;

public class Ps
{
}
```

PsList.java

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class PsList implements List<Ps>
{
    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Ps> iterator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray()
    {
        return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Ps ps)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Ps> c)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Ps> c)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Ps get(int index)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Ps set(int index, Ps element)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Ps element)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Ps remove(int index)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Ps> listIterator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Ps> listIterator(int index)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Ps> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

OtherService.java

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class OtherService
{
    private void doSomething(Map<String, List<Ps>> map, Boolean custom)
    {
        if (custom)
        {
            map.put("someValue", new PsList());
        } else {
            map.put("someValue", new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }

    private void callDoSomethingNotCustom()
    {
        Map<String, List<Ps>> map = new HashMap<>();
        doSomething(map, false);
    }

    private void callDoSomethingCustom()
    {
        Map<String, PsList> map = new HashMap<String, PsList>();
        // map is not the right format
        doSomething(map, true);
    }
}
```

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String,com.foo.PsList>', required: 'java.util.Map>'

Comment: Please could you provide a [mcve]? If it's *exactly* as you've shown, I'd expect it to work in the first part of your question.

Comment: Can't reproduce error: `doSomething(psList)` must and does compile just fine.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: It dawned on me that I need to be passing the same type of Map regardless of what gets created inside it.
private void callDoSomethingCustom()
    {
        Map<String, List<Ps>> map = new HashMap<>();
        doSomething(map, true);
    }

Comment: It would be worth editing your question further, as the first part of it (where you claim you can't pass a `PsList` as a `List<Ps>`) is untrue - it's only when you're using it as a generic type argument (in `Map<String, List<Ps>>`) that you're having problems. (This is why it's so important to provide a [mcve] from the start.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seemed to realize halfway through your question, your problem is not about `List<Ps>` being interchangeable with `PsList`.

The problem is that you can’t add to a `Map<String, ? extends List<Ps>>`.

Let’s consider a simpler example:

```
void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
    map.put(String, Integer.valueOf(0));    // Not allowed.
}
```

The problem is that `Map<String, ? extends Number>` does not mean “values can be Number or any subclass of Number.”

Every generically typed object has a specific, non-wildcard type.  Meaning, there does not exist a Map whose type is `Map<String, ? extends Number>`.  However, the following *can* exist:

- `Map<String, Integer>` (allows Integer values only)
- `Map<String, Double>` (allows Double values only)
- `Map<String, Number>` (allows values of any Number subclass)

`Map<String, ? extends Number>` refers to a Map that *might be* any one of the above (or, of course, any other specific Number subclass).  The compiler doesn’t know which specific type the Map’s values are, but the Map still has a specific type for its values which does not make use of `?` in any way.

So, looking at the example method again:

```
void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
    // Not allowed.  The caller might have passed a Map<String, Double>.
    map.put(String, Integer.valueOf(0));

    // Not allowed.  The caller might have passed a Map<String, Integer>.
    map.put(String, Double.valueOf(0));

    // Not allowed.  The caller might have passed a Map<String, Integer>
    // or Map<String, Double>.  This method has no way of knowing what the
    // actual restriction is.
    Number someNumber = generateNewNumber();
    map.put(String, someNumber);
}
```

Indeed, you cannot add anything to a Map or Collection whose type is an upper bound wildcard, because there is no way to know whether it’s correct and safe to do so.

In your case, the simplest solution is to remove the wildcard:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, List<Ps>> map, boolean custom) {
    // ...
    map.put("stringValue", custom ? new PsList() : new ArrayList<Ps>());
}
```

If you really have Maps with different value types, you would need to tell the method the specific type being used:

```
private <L extends List<Ps>> void doSomething(Map<String, L> map,
                                              Supplier<L> listCreator) {
    // ...

    map.put("stringValue", listCreator.get());
}
```

And then you can call the method like this:

```
if (custom) {
    doSomething(psMap, PsList::new);
} else {
    doSomething(listMap, ArrayList::new);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful for understanding what the heck was going on. Saved me some head + wall time, I'm sure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do that. Here is an example:

```
public class MyClass {

    static interface FooList<T> {}
    static class Ps {}

    static void doSomething(FooList<Ps> list) { }

    static class PsList implements FooList<Ps> { }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FooList psList = new PsList();

        doSomething(psList);

        System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
    }
}
```

See demo [here](http://jdoodle.com/a/1Ekf).